# JQUERY Forward paging in REST API with deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, jquery-deferred

I have REST API in jSON format for fetching record.

> My Logic

1. REST API fetch record (jSON format)
2. I fetch top 6 records, while I fetch record I will get one more jSON node which will have forward paging URL. I am assigning this URL to HTML5 button to data-url attribute.
3. Then I will get that data-url on button click, I use this URL to repeat point 1-3. I will repeat above process until paging URL is not undefined

> My Code

```
$.when(processList(url)).done(function () { });

function processList(nextUrl) {
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    if (nextUrl == undefined) {
      $("#btnViewMore").hide();
      dfd.resolve();
      return;
    }
    var news = ""
    getData(nextUrl).done(function (data) {
      var items = data.d.results;
      var next = data.d.__next;
      $("#btnViewMore").removeAttr("data-url").attr("data-url", next).show();
      dfd.resolve();

      // $.when(processList(next)).done(function () {
      //   dfd.resolve();
      // });


      $.each(items, function (i, item) {
        // display record
      })
      $("#news").append(news);
    })
    return dfd.promise();
  }
```

> Button Click

```
$("#btnViewMore").click(function () {
      var _url = $(this).data('url')
      $.when(processList(_url)).done(function () { });
    })
```

> My HTML5 Button

```
<button type="button" name="" id="btnViewMore" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" style="display:none">View More
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Now my issue if I run full record fetch with $.when inside getData it will bring all records properly. **But when I assign url to button then it start repeating same record again and again. I found out that URL is not changing with new URL due to that it is repeating data**

Please let me know how can I solve this

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you mix `data` and `attr` methods. Both methods return same value on start but after that and changes you make in code gives different results. `data` and `attr` changes do not reflect to  each other.

Use **ONLY** `data` method in javascript to get and set data

[**Demo Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ergec/u09278d1/)

```
var $mybutton = $("#mybutton");
var $body = $("body");
//Outputs correct url set in HTML
$body.append("Original 'data': " + $mybutton.data("url") + "<br>");
$body.append("Original 'attr': " + $mybutton.attr("data-url") + "<br>");
//Set url using attr method
$mybutton.attr("data-url", "http://www.yahoo.com");
//Output url using attr method
$body.append("NOT Updated 'data': " + $mybutton.data("url") + "<br>");
//Output url using data method
$body.append("Updated 'attr': " + $mybutton.attr("data-url") + "<br>");
//Set url using data method
$mybutton.data("url", "http://www.yandex.com");
//Output url using attr method
$body.append("Updated 'data': " + $mybutton.data("url") + "<br>");
//Output url using data method
$body.append("NOT Updated 'attr': " + $mybutton.attr("data-url") + "<br>");
```